How to set one of the standard pixmaps on a label in PySide6?
I'm trying to set a standard pixmap on a label, but nothing I do works.
I tried:
self.konfiguracja_groupBox.findChildren(qtw.QLabel, "polaczenie_label")[0].setPixmap(self.style().standardIcon(qtw.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxCritical))

which throws:
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QLabel.setPixmap' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QLabel.setPixmap(QIcon)
Supported signatures:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QLabel.setPixmap(Union[PySide6.QtGui.QPixmap, PySide6.QtGui.QImage])

and
self.konfiguracja_groupBox.findChildren(qtw.QLabel, "polaczenie_label")[0].setPixmap(qtw.QStyle.standardPixmap(qtw.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxWarning))

which throws:
TypeError: descriptor 'standardPixmap' for 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QStyle' objects doesn't apply to a 'StandardPixmap' object

Sorry that I can't provide the minimal example, the app was set up using QTDesigner plus I don't know what I'm doing.

As the error suggests, you're trying to call setPixmap() with a QIcon, but it only accepts QPixmaps. Check the QIcon documentation, as it has a dedicated pixmap() function.

Firstly, standardPixmap is deprecated, so it should be avoided. Secondly, it's not static, so it must be called on an instance of QStyle, not the class. But anyway, the correct solution is to do e.g. label.setPixmap(label.style().standardIcon( QStyle.SP_MessageBoxWarning).pixmap()).

@musicamante I checked the fricking docs. setPixmap wants pixmap. standardPixmap returns it. standardPixmap wants StandardPixmap. I give it. It doesn't work

@ekhumoro That helped, though I had to change it to self.label.setPixmap(self.style().standardIcon(qtw.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxWarning).pixmap(100))

@Radar32 standardPixmap() does work, but only if used properly with an instance of QStyle, yet you were using it inappropriately as a static method as ekhumoro wrote, so it should be self.style().standardPixmap(...) instead; then again, it's deprecated, and you should use standardIcon(). The size argument is mandatory for all QIcon.pixmap() overloads (as the docs suggest): QIcon does not "contain" a pixmap at a specific size; in fact, it could have many pixmaps or even no pixmap at all, as they could be generated dynamically (eg. SVG icons).
